# How to remove a second keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

At some point I added a additional keyboard layout as well as English. I have since deleted it. But whenever I boot up and get to the sign in screen, the (supposedly deleted) other language layout is the default, and so if I type the password blindly, it is wrong.

I have to go the top right and change the keyboard layout to English before entering my password.

But when I go to `settings` and `Language and Region` to delete this other language, there is only one language listed:

[image]

---

Output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBLAYOUT=cm,us
XKBVARIANT=dvorak,
BACKSPACE=guess
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the output of this terminal command: `cat /etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: Have done that, thanks. The second language (cm) does appear. Can I remove it in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it manually. Run this command to open it for editing:

```
gedit admin:///etc/default/keyboard
```

Then change it so it simply looks like this:

```
XKBLAYOUT=us
BACKSPACE=guess
```

Then save and reboot.

Comment: This worked, thank you! How do I learn this stuff??